# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch' by 1 commit

Tags: git

I know that this question has already been talked a lot in SO. But please bear with me.

My senior had created a branch called `mav921`, I was instructed to checkout that branch and work on it.

So what I did was, `git checkout -b local-mav921 origin/mav921`,

It worked.

As I finished my task being in `local-mav921` branch, I wanted to push it, so I did

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

but the commit said:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/mav921' by 1 commit.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
... all the files that I was working.
```

Basically, what happened is after running `add & commit`, it did not commit my work.

so, I tried to push as per error message: `git push`, and it says:

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

git push origin HEAD:mav921

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

git push origin HEAD
```

when running `git branch -a`:

```
    Mav921
    mav921
*   local-mav921
    master
    remotes/origin/mav921
    remotes/origin/master
```

You can notice that I have `Mav921` (don't mind this because I created this from master).
.
also, `mav921` (This is because I checked out the one from remote without creating a new branch that bases to that branch).
And finally, `local-mav921` (is the result of running git `checkout -b local-mav921 origin/mav921`)

To be honest, I don't have any idea how to resolve this. It would be great if someone can enlighten me as to what is happening and how to resolve this.

Comment: Consider renaming the branch to `mav921` from `local-mav921` using `git branch -m mav921`?  The `local-` part is kinda unneeded. Then you should be able to push without being too specific.

Comment: It sure looks like git committed locally for you, and that's why it says `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/mav921' by 1 commit.`, that 1 commit is the one you just made. Isn't this just about pushing back to the origin?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen How do I push back to the origin? I'm sorry, really noob with version control.

Comment: What about `git push origin local-mav921:mav921`? Or doing what the git output said `git push origin HEAD:mav921`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, Yes, that's why I posted in SO first to be sure.

Anyways, I suppose that `git push origin local-mav921:mav921` will push all my changes from `local-mav921` to the remote branch `mav921` right?, also `git push origin HEAD:mav921` does the same?

Comment: `HEAD` points to whatever commit/branch you currently have checked out. So if you're on `mav921` then yes. If you have another branch checked out, then no.

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox. understood the cause[ and the flow.

Comment: You need to do something also about the branches Mav921 and mav921. This is a bad situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what I did was, `git checkout -b local-mav921 origin/mav921`

So now your local branch has a different name from the remote branch that it tracks. That's unusual but neither illegal nor fatal. But it does mean that certain Git shortcut commands won't work.

> Basically, what happened is after running add & commit, it did not commit my work.

Yes it did. It committed your work just fine. That is why you are ahead of the remote; you made a new commit.

> I tried to push as per error message: `git push`, and it says:
> *fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
> the name of your current branch*

Indeed. As I said at the start, you've done an unusual thing. Your local and remote branch names don't match. This means that shortcuts like simple `git push` don't work. You therefore have to give the command in its full form. But that's no problem! It's easy. And the message tells exactly you how to do it:

```
git push origin HEAD:mav921
```

So do that.